# What site do I ask the question "Where do find an {MSI,RPM,EXE,DPG,DMG} package for $OSS_PROGRAM" that is only distributed via source and a binary zipfile

Tags: discussion, questions

Ok so I want to ask "Where can I find an MSI for installing Eclipse," since eclipse only seems to distribute it as a tarball/zip of compiled binaries. I'm not sure which site to ask it on. Here's my justification for each:

- **Stackoverflow** - An IDE is used for programming, therefore its a programming question
- **Serverfault** - A systemadministrator for a company that writes java apps on windows machines might want to use or provide to his users eclipse MSIs
- **Super User** - It't not directly programming related and not directly server related.

Being I've had [a similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/25483/where-can-i-get-windows-builds-of-ffmpeg-closed) closed on serverfault because it was not considered programing related, I figured, let me ask where to ask.

**Edit**: I asked the question poorly. reworded it.

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand why this question has to be asked at all.

Maybe I'm just not familiar enough with Eclipse, but "where do I download an installer for Eclipse" seems to be a question of zero value, to me.

Where do you download Visual Studio? TextMate?

That's not about programming, it's a basic Internet 101 question.

Comment: I think he's just confused by the fact that eclipse comes as zip file and there is no need to "install" it. Yes, a basic question, but in this day and age of installers for everything you can see how a new user might be confused.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I want an MSI. I am more than capable of installing a zip file. When I encounter this problem with small OSS projects, I usually write an MSI and give it to the author to include in the source project.

Most eclipse distros are distributed via zip files. However some, Apache Directory Studio realize the importance (at least in my mind) of having a proper installer for your software.

Comment: This seems pretty clear-cut then, as it's not really a question about Eclipse... If you need an MSI for some sort of automated deployment thing, ask on SF; if you just don't like manually creating directories and unzipping files, SU; if you need help *making* the MSI, SO.

Comment: @Shog9 FTW! +1.

Answer (score 2):

Post it on StackOverflow.

There are a lot of IDE questions there.

Comment: The reason for many IDE questions on stackoverflow probably has more to do with Stackoverflow being the first site up, than it being the best place to ask these questions now.

As a matter of fact, I expect that as membership grows and rules become more clearly defined for what category of questions go where for edge cases, that contributors with too much time on their hands will go looking for miscatagorized questions and move them between sites.

In other words, I'm hoping for a wikipedia like cabal of contributors to form.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install eclipse` or `sudo pacman -Sy eclipse` ;) (See [win-get](http://windows-get.sourceforge.net/index.php), that has an <del>[Eclipse entry](http://windows-get.sourceforge.net/listapps.php?cat=Editors)</del> [Broken download]. Also see [WPKG](http://wpkg.org/).)

---

I think that this is more of a question for Super User.

It's not *programming related* per sé. If it were how to deploy Eclipse across several computers easily, it might be Server Fault worthy.

I mean, it's about *installing* the application, not about how to setup the programming environment (which would be OK in SO, IMHO), or how to build from source.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a server software, then serverfault, if it is a development tool like Eclipse, then Stack Overflow. If it is more of an end user utility, then probably SuperUser

Comment: That seems a bit like repeating obvious points on an old question just to put the link to your site, you know?

Comment: Also, you put "game" for Super User. You deserve my -1.

Comment: The distinction between server-side, development tool or end-user tool was never made. There is a lot of open source out there, each one packaged for a difference audience. StackOverflow and related sites is 0.2% of our traffic so I kind of have to chuckle at your suggestion, but anyways just to avoid any doubt, I removed the reference to Bitnami.

Comment: @Daniel - when you know the purpose of each of these sites, it was a bit stating the obvious: "Server related to SF, programming related to SO, end user to SU". This is why I said that, moreover with including your link in it. Have a nice chuckling.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself clearly. Justin was asking where it would be more appropriate to post a question about an MSI for a particular piece of software. In the question he suggested it could be potentially posted to any of the three sites (for example because an admin may want to distribute those MSIs, hence it may be a serverfault question). My suggestion was to look at it from the angle of not how the software being packaged in an MSI may be used by different people but of the category of the software itself. In the Eclipse particular case, it is a development tool so it belongs to SO

Comment: @Daniel - And this view is too simple, because in the case of Eclipse, Super User is correct as well.